# Who is responsible for the cab fare increase due to waiting for a drug control to be completed at a checkpoint in Thailand?

Tags: thailand, taxis, bangkok, drugs, officials

If the passenger of a taxi get screened  by the police for drug at a random street checkpoint in Thailand, who is responsible for the cab fare increase due to waiting for a drug control to be completed? E.g., is the police supposed to pay for the cab fare increase? I'm mostly interested in Bangkok if the answer depends on the city.

Comment: Is that a rhetorical question?

Comment: @Traveller No~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: You will probably find that the city authorities won't pay the waiting time at a red light either.

Comment: @WeatherVane If you know the answer please write one.

Comment: This seems like more of a question about [Law.SE] than about travel.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is to pay off the driver, and hail another cab when the police let you proceed.

Comment: Would the police allow that? If so, it would be really easy for a passenger carrying drugs to tuck them under a seat on approaching the checkpoint. If not stopped, retrieve them after passing the checkpoint. If stopped, send the taxi, with the drugs, on its way.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan not being stopped is irrelevant. But if you pay off the driver and leave the drugs on board, then I don't suppose you'll ever see them again, and the checkpoint has served its purpose in some way.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan if the passenger ends the ride that does not necessarily mean that the taxi and its driver can avoid the checkpoint.  If that is the case then the solution might be seen as less than ethical.

Comment: @WeatherVane The implication is that the taxi driver is in on it too.

Answer (score 5):

Generally you are responsible for any fare incurred until the cab send you to your destination. If you get stopped usually it is a quick questioning and police will let you go. If they suspect you then next step will be longer search and likely that the driver will excuse himself. If you are lucky the driver may not care to ask for fare!!

In most case you can ask the driver to stop the meter and resume charging when the trip resume.